# How would one do > x < in C#

Tags: c#, random

I'm attempting to make a random number generator that then selects one of three options based on the random number. I would like to use > x < as the second choice of three but it gives me an error:

Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'

Here's the code:

```
        int rand;
        Random myRandom = new Random();
        rand = myRandom.Next(0, 90);

        if (rand < 33)
        {

        }

        if (33 > rand < 66)
        {

        }

        if (rand > 66)
        {

        }
```

Comment: what do you even mean by that? doesn't make any sense...

Comment: You don't even need the and. Just do if rand < 33 else if rand < 67 else if rand > 66. You will have the same outcome but it would run one less operation if running through the whole if blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the simplest option is to use `else if` so you only need to check one condition anyway - which means it would handle 33 as well (currently not handled):

```
if (rand < 33)
{
    Console.WriteLine("rand was in the range [0, 32]");
}
else if (rand < 66)
{
    Console.WriteLine("rand was in the range [33, 65]");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("rand was in the range [66, 89]");
}
```

If you *do* need to test two conditions, however, you just want `&&` to check that they're both true:

```
// I've deliberately made this >= rather than 33. If you really don't want to do
// anything for 33, it would be worth making that clear.
if (rand >= 33 && rand < 66)
```

If you find yourself doing this a lot, you might want to have an extension method so you can say:

```
if (rand.IsInRange(33, 66))
```

where `IsInRange` would just be:

```
public static bool IsInRange(this int value, int minInclusive, int maxExclusive)
{
    return value >= minInclusive && value < maxExclusive;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the and `&&` operator as in

```
if (rand > 33 && rand < 66)
{

}
```

This makes sure the rand is `less than` `AND` `greater` then the values specified

Comment: You should also consider handling the limit values (in this case 33 and 66).

Answer (score 0):

To check the both bounds of the value you need two comparisons.

You probably want to use the `<=` operator instead of `<` in that comparison, otherwise the code will do nothing for the values `33` and `66`:

```
    if (rand < 33)
    {

    }

    if (33 <= rand && rand < 66)
    {

    }

    if (rand >= 66)
    {

    }
```

You can also use `else` to get rid of some comparisons:

```
    if (rand < 33)
    {

    }
    else if (rand < 66)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
```

Note: You have a random value between `0` and `89`, so if you want each `if` statement to be used in one third of the cases, you would use values `30` and `60` instead of `33` and `66`.